# Nginx SSL on localhost

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, localhost

I am trying to configure SSL on my localhost using Nginx. I created a self signed certificate and my nginx configuration is as below.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

But when I try accessing it gives me following error

```
$ curl -i https://localhost            
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused
```

What could be the possible cause for this error?

This is the output of command 'netstat -tuplen'

`tcp    0     0 0.0.0.0:443     0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN     0    71662`    -

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your options for `ssl_ciphers` is [considered valid](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_ciphers).

> ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 ***or*** HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";

Try setting this to `ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;"`. If it works, you can opt to configure a more secure cipher list using https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with iptable rules. I fixed it.